# Can I use multiple wildcards in .nuspec file paths?

Tags: nuget, octopus-deploy, nuspec, nuget-spec

I am attempting to collect a series of Razor views into a NuGet package using [.nuspec `<files>` elements](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#file-element-examples). My project structure is non-standard, however, for reasons I won't get into, I cannot change it.

Here's my project structure:

```
* Project
  * Bar
     * code
         * Bar.csproj <-- OctoPack initiated from here
         * Views
             * Bar
                 * View1.cshtml
                 * View2.cshtml
  * Baz
     * code
         * Views
             * Baz
                 * View3.cshtml
                 * View4.cshtml
  * Qux
     * code
         * Views
             * Qux
                 * View5.cshtml
                 * View6.cshtml
```

... and here is what I'm after:

### Desired Result

```
* Views
    * Bar
        * View1.cshtml
        * View2.cshtml
    * Baz
        * View3.cshtml
        * View4.cshtml
    * Qux
        * View5.cshtml
        * View6.cshtml
```

Here is what i've tried:

### Attempt #1

```
<file src="..\..\..\Project\*\code\Views\**\*.cshtml" target="Views" />
```

Strangely, the single wildcard becomes the recursive starting point, resulting in:

```
* Views
    * Bar
        * code
            * Views
                * View1.cshtml
                * View2.cshtml
    * Baz
        * code
            * Views
                * View3.cshtml
                * View4.cshtml
    ...
```

### Attempt #2

```
<file src="..\..\..\Project\**\code\Views\**\*.cshtml" target="Views" />
```

Produces the same result as #1

### Attempt #3

```
<file src="..\..\..\Project\*\code\Views\*\*.cshtml" target="Views" />
```

Results in the following:

```
* Views
    * View1.cshtml
    * View2.cshtml
    * View3.cshtml
    * View4.cshtml
    * View5.cshtml
    * View6.cshtml
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are building sln file with Octopack, You will need 3 nuspec files named with the same named and located   csprojectfilename.nuspec

The  section must like the following

Bar.nuspec (Same folder level with Bar.csproj)

```
<file src="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Views\bar\*.cshtml"     target="Views\Bar"/>
```

Baz.nuspec (Same folder level with Baz.csproj)

```
<file src="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Views\baz\*.cshtml"     target="Views\Baz"/>
```

Qux.nuspec (Same folder level with Qux.csproj)

```
<file src="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Views\qux\*.cshtml"     target="Views\Qux"/>
```

There will be 3 nuget packages.

**OR (without octopack)**

If you want to do this with one nuget package you should use nuget.exe and package manually.

```
"C:\Scripts\Nuget.exe" pack %WORKSPACE%\Allfilesources.nuspec -OutputDirectory "%2" -BasePath "%3" -version %4
```

**Allfilesources.nuspec**

```
<file src="C:\CustomPack\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Views\bar\*.cshtml"     target="Views\Bar"/>
<file src="C:\CustomPack\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Views\baz\*.cshtml"     target="Views\Baz"/>
<file src="C:\CustomPack\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Views\qux\*.cshtml"     target="Views\Qux"/>
```